# Bootstrap - center div's with col-ld-*

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a section with projects. This projects now are only 3, but I'm still adding new projects. The problem is that when size screen is between `768px` and `1200px` my `div` are 2 in row while the 3rd is in new line and it's okay, but is possibility to be this 3rd div in center of row?

Now last is on the left new line. It'll be better look to be in center.
I mean, that when one div is on the new line and is alone I want to be it on the center row.

Here is my bootstrap code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="no-padding" id="portfolio">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h2 class="section-heading text-center">Projects</h2>
    <hr class="primary">
    <div class="row no-gutter center-block">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="portfolio-box">
          <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnails/skull.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
          <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
            <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
              <div class="project-category text-faded">
                Visits system
              </div>
              <div class="project-name">
                Hospital
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="bg-dark gitHub">
          <div class="text-center gitLink">
            <a href="#" target="_blank">Source code</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="portfolio-box">
          <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnails/pets1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
          <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
            <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
              <div class="project-category text-faded">
                Shopping
              </div>
              <div class="project-name">
                Shop
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="bg-dark gitHub">
          <div class="text-center gitLink">
            <a href="#" target="_blank">Source code</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 center-block">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="portfolio-box">
          <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnails/forum.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
          <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
            <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
              <div class="project-category text-faded">
                Under construction
              </div>
              <div class="project-name">
                Forum
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="bg-dark gitHub">
          <div class="text-center gitLink">
            <a href="#" target="_blank">Source code</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

It looks like this now, I want to be last div on the center - is it possible by responsive screens?[image]

When I add col-md-offset-3 over 1200 px It looks now like this:

[image]

Comment: You mean that the new order will be like: 1st 3rd 2nd?

Comment: Center but still in the next line?

Comment: I added a foto how it looks now, I would like to be last div on the center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-lg-offset-0">
            <a href="#" target="_blank" class="portfolio-box">
                <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnails/forum.jpg" 
                class="img-responsive" alt="">
                <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                    <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                        <div class="project-category text-faded">
                            Under construction
                        </div>
                        <div class="project-name">
                            Forum
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="bg-dark gitHub">
                <div class="text-center gitLink">
                    <a href="#" target="_blank">Source code</a>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Adding offset when the screen is small should make it work.

Comment: this works now good between 768 and 1200 px but, when I have 1200px now this looks bad - I added foto. This offset destroy everything over 1200px

Comment: Have updated the answer , please check it and let me know if it works .

Comment: It works, but It's not in the center between 992 and 1200 px now. On the rest sizes It looks good.

Comment: oh my bad , i should i have given offset 0 in lg ... Editting .

Comment: Yes! It works now... I have a lot to study with bootstrap. Thx!

Comment: Can You tell me just why It works on lg, but didn't with md?

Comment: Because we have set lg-4 and sm-6 , sm-6 means 6 columns for sm and above unless explicitly specified . So by default md is also 6 (both with size and offset). lg is 4 hence it does not need offset , hence offset 0 there. Do read up on how grids work in Bootstrap , they have a very sweet and easy documentation there. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add "col-sm-offset-3" to your last column and remove you class "center-block". This will give the expected output

Answer (score 0):

Added color for visualization, add `col-sm-offset-3` to the 3rd div then remove that `center-block`. I also added the `col-xs-*` so that you can see it in the snippet

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="no-padding" id="portfolio">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h2 class="section-heading text-center">Projects</h2>
    <hr class="primary">
    <div class="row no-gutter center-block">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="background-color:red">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="portfolio-box">
          <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnails/skull.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
          <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
            <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
              <div class="project-category text-faded">
                Visits system
              </div>
              <div class="project-name">
                Hospital
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="bg-dark gitHub">
          <div class="text-center gitLink">
            <a href="#" target="_blank">Source code</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="background-color:blue">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="portfolio-box">
          <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnails/pets1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
          <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
            <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
              <div class="project-category text-faded">
                Shopping
              </div>
              <div class="project-name">
                Shop
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="bg-dark gitHub">
          <div class="text-center gitLink">
            <a href="#" target="_blank">Source code</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3" style="background-color:pink">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="portfolio-box">
          <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnails/forum.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
          <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
            <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
              <div class="project-category text-faded">
                Under construction
              </div>
              <div class="project-name">
                Forum
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="bg-dark gitHub">
          <div class="text-center gitLink">
            <a href="#" target="_blank">Source code</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```